# Cannot add dynos on Heroku app after seemingly successful app push

Tags: python, heroku

I recently launched an app on Heroku using `git push heroku master` and got a couple of errors:

```
remote:            raise ValueError("Missing distribution spec", line)
remote:        ValueError: ('Missing distribution spec', '+ Python (2.7)')
```

However, I then got

```
remote: -----> Compressing... done, 36.5MB
remote: -----> Launching... done, v5
```

suggesting the app was launched successfully.

Unfortunately if I attempt to access the page hosting the app I get a page with the message:

```
An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served. Please try again in a few moments.

If you are the application owner, check your logs for details.
```

I checked the logs and it states there's an error whose code is H14 - the application has no dynos associated with it.  Naturally I went to add a dyno, but Heroku won't let me add one at all.  The 'edit' option isn't around at all.  I checked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18968910/not-able-to-add-dynos-on-heroku) and found that it wasn't really similar to my situation, since to my knowledge Heroku let me launch the app, and so I assumed the above errors were not critical.  What am I missing?

See below for the full `git push` output.

```
Counting objects: 197, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (193/193), done.
Writing objects: 100% (197/197), 1.95 MiB | 390.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 197 (delta 14), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote: 
remote: -----> Python app detected
remote: -----> Stack changed, re-installing runtime
remote: -----> Installing runtime (python-2.7.9)
remote: -----> Installing dependencies with pip
remote:        Exception:
remote:        Traceback (most recent call last):
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.5.6-py2.7.egg/pip/basecommand.py", line 122, in main
remote:            status = self.run(options, args)
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.5.6-py2.7.egg/pip/commands/install.py", line 262, in run
remote:            for req in parse_requirements(filename, finder=finder, options=options, session=session):
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.5.6-py2.7.egg/pip/req.py", line 1631, in parse_requirements
remote:            req = InstallRequirement.from_line(line, comes_from, prereleases=getattr(options, "pre", None))
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.5.6-py2.7.egg/pip/req.py", line 172, in from_line
remote:            return cls(req, comes_from, url=url, prereleases=prereleases
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.5.6-py2.7.egg/pip/req.py", line 70, in __init__
remote:            req = pkg_resources.Requirement.parse(req)
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.5.6-py2.7.egg/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources.py", line 2667, in parse
remote:            reqs = list(parse_requirements(s))
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.5.6-py2.7.egg/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources.py", line 2593, in parse_requirements
remote:            raise ValueError("Missing distribution spec", line)
remote:        ValueError: ('Missing distribution spec', '+ Python (2.7)')
remote:        
remote:        Storing debug log for failure in /app/.pip/pip.log
remote: 
remote: -----> Preparing static assets
remote:        Collectstatic configuration error. To debug, run:
remote:        $ heroku run python ./manage.py collectstatic --noinput
remote: 
remote: -----> Discovering process types
remote:        Procfile declares types -> (none)
remote: 
remote: -----> Compressing... done, 36.5MB
remote: -----> Launching... done, v5
remote:        https://firsttest.herokuapp.com/ deployed to Heroku
remote: 
remote: Verifying deploy... done.
To https://git.heroku.com/firsttest.git
```

Comment: Post the _complete_ output from `git push`.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Added, let me know if there's anything else that might be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You have a syntax error in your `requirements.txt`: the line

```
+ Python (2.7)
```

is invalid. If that is supposed to be a comment it should start with a `#`.